# Create oracle procedure which returns db-entities

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, stored-procedures, intellij-idea

I am currently working on two Java Web Applications. One uses a PostgreSQL-Database, another one an Oracle-Database. IDE is Intellij, OS is Windows.
With the Postgres Application we have many stored procedures to return database entities, e.g. "customers". Now I am trying to do the same in Oracle, but it seems that procedures in Oracle are not the same at all. I can't even create a procedure, Intellij always gives me several error messages when trying to. :-( Maybe someone can give me an example of how to create a simple procedure which returns a List of db entities from one table, depending on several parameters from a search mask, for example "name", "last_name", "email" as search parameters? That's be great!!

Comment: Start from here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm and ask more questions if necessary

Comment: Actually I already did, but still have no clue how to achieve what I want...

Comment: You're looking for a function http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php that returns a type

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_Employees(
  in_first_name IN  EMPLOYEES.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
  in_last_name  IN  EMPLOYEES.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
  in_email      IN  EMPLOYEES.EMAIL%TYPE,
  out_cursor    OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN OUT_CURSOR FOR
  SELECT *
  FROM   Employees
  WHERE  ( in_last_name IS NULL OR last_name = in_last_name )
  AND    ( in_first_name IS NULL OR first_name = in_first_name )
  AND    ( in_email IS NULL OR email = in_email );
END;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

**Testing**:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees ( First_name, last_name, email ) AS
SELECT 'Alice',   'Abbots', 'AA@email.net' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bob',     'Bucket', 'BB@email.net' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Charlie', 'Abbots', 'CA@email.net' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Denis',   'Dobbs',  'DD@email.net' FROM DUAL;
```

The run:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

BEGIN
  get_Employees(
    in_first_name => 'Bob',
    in_last_name  => NULL,
    in_email      => NULL,
    out_cursor    => :cur
  );
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Which should output:

```
anonymous block completed
CUR
---
FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME EMAIL        
---------- --------- ------------ 
Bob        Bucket    BB@email.net
```

Alternative test:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
  rec EMPLOYEES%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  get_Employees(
    in_first_name => 'Bob',
    in_last_name  => NULL,
    in_email      => NULL,
    out_cursor    => cur
  );

  LOOP
    FETCH cur INTO rec;
    EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( rec.first_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( ' ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( rec.last_name );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( ' ' );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( rec.email );
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE cur;
END;
/
```

Comment: Nice, could this be improved by using the in parameters as bind variables in the cursor?  (less chance of injection, better performance)

Comment: @kevinsky The `IN` parameters are bind variables. In a PL/SQL scope you do not need to prefix PL/SQL variables with `:` for them to be bind variables (they are automatically). You only need to prefix variables defined in an SQL scope.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask why the '/' after END;?

Comment: How would I execute the procedure to test it?

Comment: A statement is terminated with a `;` and a PL/SQL block (which can contain many statements) is terminated with a `/`. One sample test added - I ran it in Oracle's SQL Developer but you should be able to run it in any SQL client.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that the keyword "Variable" is not recognized, neither in Intellij 15 nor in DBVisualizer 9.13. I can't execute the procedure the way you did. It throws me a lot of "ORA-00900" errors...

Comment: Updated with a different method of doing the test - run it as a script (I think, from what I've read, `CTRL-SHIFT-F10` in Intellij) rather than as a statement. Again, I've only tested it in SQL Developer.

Comment: Complex SQL statements that includes ; as part of the statement must be executed differently in DbVisualizer. Please check http://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG92/Executing+Complex+Statements